# Additing two array variable in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am building a system where i need to update the value in the database field but before doing that i need to take the current value in the database then adding it to the current value the following is a code from the controller.

```
public function transfer_amount(){



    $email  =  $this->input->post('view');

    $this->load->model('user_model');

    $data['user_balance'] = $this->user_model->fetch_balance($email);

    $data['balance'] = $this->input->post('amount');

    $data['total'] = $this->math->add($data['balance'],$data['user_balance']);


    $data = array(

            'balance' => $data['total'],

    );




    if($this->user_model->transfer_amount($data,$email)== true){


        $this->load->view('layer_service/success',$data);


    }
    else
    {


        $this->load->view('layer_service/unsuccessfull',$data);
    }



}
```

}

then the code in the module that fetch the current balance from the database is as following.

```
 function fetch_balance($email){


    $this->db->select('balance');
    $this->db->from('tbl_users');
    $this->db->where('email', $email);

    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result();

    return $result;


}
```

Comment: And what? What is the problem?

Comment: code is not work gives me error it doesnt understand math

Comment: What is `$this->math->add()`?  What library provides that?  Also, `fetch_balance()` returns an array of objects, not one value.

Comment: i have not worked with math in codeigniter all i need is help i guess i have explained the picture of what i am trying to archive

Comment: Of course it doesn't understand `math` thing, that's too normal. Just tell me, what would you like to do? What is your point?

Comment: I would like to add the value present in the database with the New value I get from post then after I update the database

Comment: Please if one has worked with addition operation in codeigniter need help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure but look at this part - don't call it $data because i think thats messing you up later

for example call it $balance

```
  $balance = array(

            'balance' => $data['total'],

    );

    // pass the $balance to your model method
    if($this->user_model->transfer_amount($balance,$email) == true){

       // keeping $data here to pass to the view 
        $this->load->view('layer_service/success',$data);

    }
```

getting the balance should be wrapped in an if in case it fails

```
if( ! $data['user_balance'] = $this->user_model->fetch_balance($email) )
{
   $this->_showNoUserFor($email) ; 
}
```

another suggestion:

```
$email  =  $this->input->post('view');
```

validate the email first before sending it to your database table. codeigniter form validation library works really well.

======

EDIT ok this part

```
 $data['total'] =   $this->math->add($data['balance'],$data['user_balance']);
```

means that you have a model called math with a method called add()
so if you don't have that you would just use php math which is very simple

```
$data['total'] = $data['balance'] + $data['user_balance'] ;
```

of course this assumes everything has been validated first so you are actually adding together two numbers.

Comment: Thank  you but the problem comes on how to add (apply mathematical expression) in the code please assist